# Using enums as the options values on ipywidgets

Tags: python, matplotlib, interaction, ipywidgets

I want to make an interaction with an ipywidgets Dropdown which goes on to create a barchart. The bars of the barchart can be ordered in different ways.

I have an enum of the types of sorting I wish to give as options:

```
class SORT_TYPE(Enum):
    ALPHABETICAL = 1
    ASCENDING = 2
    DESCENDING = 3
    UNSORTED = 4
```

I have a dropdown widget where the values use the enum above

```
ordering_dropdown = widgets.Dropdown(
    options={'Alphabetical': SORT_TYPE.ALPHABETICAL, \
             'Ascending': SORT_TYPE.ASCENDING, \
             'Descending': SORT_TYPE.DESCENDING, \
             'Unsorted': SORT_TYPE.UNSORTED},
    value=SORT_TYPE.ALPHABETICAL,
    description='Ordering: ',
)
```

But when I go to use it in an interaction

```
interactive(my_func, p1=p1, p2=p2, ordering=ordering_dropdown)
```

I get

```
ValueError: <SORT_TYPE.ALPHABETICAL: 1> cannot be transformed to a widget
```

Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think your original code will work if you change the value you pass to `options` from a `dict[str, Enum]` to a `list[tuple[str, Enum]]`. In other words, from `{'Alphabetical': SORT_TYPE.ALPHABETICAL, ...}` to `[('Alphabetical', SORT_TYPE.ALPHABETICAL), ...]`. See my answer for more details on why, and for how you might use a `StrEnum` for this.

Answer (score 1):

While you *can* define your own mappings and treat them as constants, [`IntEnum` (standard library)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.IntEnum) and [`StrEnum` (third party package, but in the standard library as of Python 3.11)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58608361/string-based-enum-in-python) are closer to your original intent:

```py
In [1]: from enum import IntEnum

In [2]: class MyEnum(IntEnum):
   ...:     ONE = 1
   ...:     TWO = 2
   ...:

In [3]: MyEnum.TWO
Out[3]: <MyEnum.TWO: 2>

In [4]: MyEnum.TWO.value  # <-- deflate via the value property
Out[4]: 2

In [5]: MyEnum(2)  # <-- reinflate by passing the int value to the constructor
Out[5]: <MyEnum.TWO: 2>
```

If you don't have access to `StrEnum`, then you can use a trick identified by the aforementioned SE answer to approximate something similar. We can exploit a certain property of selection widgets (e.g., `Dropdown`, `RadioButtons`, etc.) to afford automated translation between the strings and the enums. From [the docs](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20List.html#Selection-widgets):

> You can specify the **enumeration of selectable options by passing a
> list** (options are either (label, value) pairs, or simply values for
> which the labels are derived by calling `str`).

The affords enum semantics with a tighter relationship between strings and their corresponding enum values.

```py
class SORT_TYPE(str, Enum):  # <-- or just StrEnum, if you have it
    ALPHABETICAL = "Alphabetical"
    ASCENDING = "Descending"
    DESCENDING = "Descending"
    UNSORTED = "Unsorted"

ordering_dropdown = widgets.Dropdown(
    options=[
        (
            sort_type.value,  # the label (a str)
            sort_type,  # the value (an enum)
        ) for sort_type in SORT_TYPE
    ],
    value=SORT_TYPE.ALPHABETICAL,  # probably must be in options
    description='Ordering: ',
)
```

Retrieving the value back from your widget will result in the enum:

```py
assert isinstance(ordering_dropdown.value, SORT_TYPE)  # should work
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering myself. Figure the error is because enums aren't a fixed type. Have changed the enum to

```
SORT_TYPE={'ALPHABETICAL': 1,\
       'ASCENDING': 2,\
       'DESCENDING': 3,\
       'UNSORTED': 4}
```

and the Dropdown to

```
ordering_dropdown = widgets.Dropdown(
       options={'Alphabetical': SORT_TYPE['ALPHABETICAL'], \
                'Ascending': SORT_TYPE['ASCENDING'], \
                'Descending': SORT_TYPE['DESCENDING'], \
                'Unsorted': SORT_TYPE['UNSORTED']},
       value=SORT_TYPE['ALPHABETICAL'],
       description='Ordering: ',
    )
```

It's behaving a bit better now.