# String-based enum in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, enums

To encapsulate a list of states I am using `enum` module:

```
from enum import Enum

class MyEnum(Enum):
    state1='state1'
    state2 = 'state2'

state = MyEnum.state1
MyEnum['state1'] == state  # here it works
'state1' == state  # here it does not throw but returns False (fail!)
```

However, the issue is that I need to seamlessly use the values as strings in many contexts in my script, like:

```
select_query1 = select(...).where(Process.status == str(MyEnum.state1))  # works but ugly

select_query2 = select(...).where(Process.status == MyEnum.state1)  # throws exeption
```

How to do it avoiding calling additional type conversion (`str(state)` above) or the underlying value (`state.value`)?

Comment: `MyEnum.state1.value`?

Comment: Sorry but this is same as ugly as `str(state)` to me...

Comment: What type is `Testround.status`? Could you make it of type `MyEnum`?

Comment: Your example code `'state1' == state` is wrong -- that comparison returns `False`.

Comment: @EthanFurman: it does not throw but indeed the result is far from satisfactory. Thanks! Correcting.

Answer (score 177, accepted):

It seems that it is enough to inherit from `str` class at the same time as `Enum`:

```py
from enum import Enum

class MyEnum(str, Enum):
    state1 = 'state1'
    state2 = 'state2'
```

The tricky part is that **the order** of classes in the inheritance chain *is important* as this:

```
class MyEnum(Enum, str):
    state1 = 'state1'
    state2 = 'state2'
```

throws:

```
TypeError: new enumerations should be created as `EnumName([mixin_type, ...] [data_type,] enum_type)`
```

With the correct class the following operations on `MyEnum` are fine:

```
print('This is the state value: ' + state)
```

---

As a side note, it seems that the special inheritance trick is not needed for [formatted strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) which work even for `Enum` inheritance only:

```
msg = f'This is the state value: {state}'  # works without inheriting from str
```

Comment: Relevant docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#restricted-enum-subclassing

Comment: Please note that a a `str` mixin may have unintended side effect, e.g. on (de)serialization behaviour; see for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/65339635/10009545

Comment: It's simpler to just subclass `StrEnum` if you're on Python 3.11+ - https://docs.python.org/3/howto/enum.html#strenum.

Comment: @TaylorD.Edmiston - as Elyasaf755 suggests below in his answer.

Comment: I used to do this but had strange behaviour on python 3.10.11, with a function returning an enum object would get deserialised to the string when assigning to a variable. Removing the str subclass fixed it and it seems to work fine without it.

Comment: I guess you can use the approach proposed by @Elyasaf755 below for newer versions of Python; particularly 3.11+

Answer (score 130):

By reading the documentation (i.e., I didn't try it because I use an older version of Python, but I trust the docs), since **Python 3.11** you can do the following:

```
from enum import StrEnum

class Directions(StrEnum):
    NORTH = 'north'
    SOUTH = 'south'

print(Directions.NORTH)
>>> north
```

Note that it looks like when subclassing StrEnum, defining the enum fields as single-value tuples will make no difference at all and would also be treated as strings, like so:

```
class Directions(StrEnum):
    NORTH = 'north',    # notice the trailing comma
    SOUTH = 'south'
```

Please refer to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.11/howto/enum.html#strenum) and the [design discussion](https://discuss.python.org/t/built-in-strenum/4192/6) for further understanding.

If you're running **python 3.6+**, execute `pip install StrEnum`, and then you can do the following (confirmed by me):

```
from strenum import StrEnum

class URLs(StrEnum):
    GOOGLE = 'www.google.com'
    STACKOVERFLOW = 'www.stackoverflow.com'

print(URLs.STACKOVERFLOW)

>>> www.stackoverflow.com
```

You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/irgeek/StrEnum).

Also, this was mentioned in the docs - how to create your own enums based on other classes:

> While IntEnum is part of the enum module, it would be very simple to
> implement independently:
>
> class IntEnum(int, Enum):
> pass This demonstrates how similar derived enumerations can be defined; for example a StrEnum that mixes in str instead of int.
>
> Some rules:
>
> When subclassing Enum, mix-in types must appear before Enum itself in
> the sequence of bases, as in the IntEnum example above.
>
> While Enum can have members of any type, once you mix in an additional
> type, all the members must have values of that type, e.g. int above.
> This restriction does not apply to mix-ins which only add methods and
> don’t specify another type.
>
> When another data type is mixed in, the value attribute is not the
> same as the enum member itself, although it is equivalent and will
> compare equal.
>
> %-style formatting: %s and %r call the Enum class’s **str**() and
> **repr**() respectively; other codes (such as %i or %h for IntEnum) treat the enum member as its mixed-in type.
>
> Formatted string literals, str.format(), and format() will use the
> mixed-in type’s **format**() unless **str**() or **format**() is
> overridden in the subclass, in which case the overridden methods or
> Enum methods will be used. Use the !s and !r format codes to force
> usage of the Enum class’s **str**() and **repr**() methods.

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#others

Comment: its 3.11 for StrEnum

Comment: Let's use auto generated enum values in serialization. Then it could be break easily by updating to buggy 'strenum' version. It's not worth it.

Comment: Doh. Doesn't work in 3.7.3 :(

Comment: This should be the correct answer for python>=3.11

Comment: Why do you include the trailing comma here: `NORTH = 'north',    # notice the trailing comma`?  I do not see this trailing comma style used anywhere in the docs.  Are you sure this is doing something?  (Subclassing `StrEnum` appears to work just fine without such commas.)

Comment: I posted this answer on the same day Python 3.10 was released (and I think before it got released on the same day). Initially, StrEnum was targetted to 3.10, and then postponed to 3.11. I didn't have 3.10, so I just copy-pasted whatever the docs said, because I couldn't test it myself and see if it actually makes any difference . Now, because the target version changed to 3.11, they removed this section from 3.10 docs, and then added a new section in 3.11 docs, where this example is not present. I found a Chinese copy of the old 3.10 docs: https://www.osgeo.cn/cpython/library/enum.html#strenum

Comment: Anyways, looks like you are correct andthe trailing comma doesn't make any djfference. I think what they wanted to note, is that unlike other classes, it doesn't matter if the enum fields are defined as single-value tuples or not, they will be treated as strings anyway? Who knows. Thanks for your comment, I will update the answer.

Comment: We can use `auto()` from `enum` with the strenum package for older python versions, but it will case fold name to lowercase by default.

Answer (score 21):

what is wrong with using the value?

Imho, unless using Python version 3.11 with StrEnum I just override the `__str__(self)` method in the proper Enum class:

```
class MyStrEnum(str, Enum):

    OK     = 'OK'
    FAILED = 'FAILED'

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.value
```

Best

Comment: but then he would still have to call `str()`  on the value or not?

Comment: No, when you are working with strings, it is not necessary to explicit call `str()`, since Python will return the internal string representation of that object then...  
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__

Comment: Top Idea +1 !!!!

Answer (score 9):

**With `auto`**

Define enum:

```py
from enum import auto
from my_utils import AutoStrEnum

class MyEnum(AutoStrEnum):
    STATE_1 = auto()
    STATE_2 = auto()
```

Use it:

```py
MyEnum.STATE_1 == "STATE_1"  # True
```

`my_utils.py`:

```py
from enum import Enum

class AutoStrEnum(str, Enum):
    """
    StrEnum where enum.auto() returns the field name.
    See https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/enum.html#using-automatic-values
    """
    @staticmethod
    def _generate_next_value_(name: str, start: int, count: int, last_values: list) -> str:
        return name
```

Comment: Usually, I prefer lower case enum:
`class AutoStrEnumLCase(str, Enum):
    def _generate_next_value_(name, start, count, last_values): return name.lower()`

Answer (score 5):

If associated string values are valid Python names then you can get names of enum members using `.name` property like this:

```
from enum import Enum
class MyEnum(Enum):
    state1=0
    state2=1

print (MyEnum.state1.name)  # 'state1'

a = MyEnum.state1
print(a.name)  # 'state1'
```

If associated string values are arbitrary strings then you can do this:

```
class ModelNames(str, Enum):
    gpt2 = 'gpt2'
    distilgpt2 = 'distilgpt2'
    gpt2_xl = 'gpt2-XL'
    gpt2_large = 'gpt2-large'

print(ModelNames.gpt2) # 'ModelNames.gpt2'
print(ModelNames.gpt2 is str) # False
print(ModelNames.gpt2_xl.name) # 'gpt2_xl'
print(ModelNames.gpt2_xl.value) # 'gpt2-XL'
```

Try this online: https://repl.it/@sytelus/enumstrtest

Answer (score 4):

While a mixin class between `str` and `Enum` can solve this problem, you should always also think about getting the **right tool for the job**.

And sometimes, the right tool could easily just be a MODULE_CONSTANT with a string value. For example, `logging` has a few constants like DEBUG, INFO, etc with meaningful values - even if they're `int`s in this case.

Enums are a good tool and I often use them. However, they're intended to be primarily compared against other members of the same Enum, which is why comparing them to, for example, strings requires you to jump through an additional hoop.

Comment: `Enum` was created so opaque module constants would not be needed.

Comment: @EthanFurman Then why are logging.DEBUG and friends not deprecated ?

Comment: They wouldn't be deprecated -- they would be replaced by a corresponding `IntEnum`.  It is standard policy to keep the stdlib as stable as possible, which means not rewriting it wholesale to take advantage of every new feature.  So far `http`, `socket`, and `re` module constants have been replaced (and maybe a couple others I don't remember at the moment).

Comment: The relevant part of [`PEP 435`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0435/#use-cases-in-the-standard-library).

Comment: @EthanFurman I recently read the arguments [here](https://mail.python.org/archives/list/python-ideas@python.org/thread/FTGUKZT4TSIGD755UQGUZOCB4VC4UUBN/#376RK7XU36QH3CJQYEVASO7NUXGBCOWJ) about it, where the more known names seemed to be in favor of keeping named constants. Some also for mixins, though less.

Comment: Wow, it feels like a long time since we had that conversation!  The main points there relate to my earlier comment: not rewriting the stdlib without good reason.  The case for magic strings is even harder to make, because the strings are usually self-explanatory.  The modules with the best chance of having `Enum` conversions are user-facing with integer constants (such as `re` and `http`).  Also, a huge reason to not convert specific portions of the stdlib is if it's used before `Enum` can be imported.  These are all reasons that do not affect code outside the stdlib.

Comment: @EthanFurman I'll be the first to grab Enum for things in a lot of places, but generally only when I (plan to) compare it to another member of the same Enum. Hence the main part of my answer: **Use the right tool for the job**. Question is *specifically* about cross-comparisons, and when those are part of the **design**, I feel Enum's aren't the right tool. But I do fully get where you're coming from.

Comment: I hear what you're saying, but how is that different than comparing one module string constant to another module string constant?

Comment: @EthanFurman IMHO, it's about intent. In my mind, Enums are compared against values that you expect an Enum of the same type, and if you want to compare to arbitrary strings, then module constants are more appropriate. There's a hint of type-safety in enums - perhaps my `moduleA` has a `class Mode(Enum):DEBUG=auto();PRODUCTION=auto()` - and that will compare unequal to your `moduleB`'s Mode Enum, even if you have the exact same code building it. If you don't want that type-safety, then perhaps you don't want enums.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to work with strings directly, you could consider using

```
MyEnum = collections.namedtuple(
    "MyEnum", ["state1", "state2"]
)(
    state1="state1", 
    state2="state2"
)
```

rather than enum at all. Iterating over this or doing `MyEnum.state1` will give the string values directly. Creating the namedtuple within the same statement means there can only be one.

Obviously there are trade offs for not using Enum, so it depends on what you value more.