# Array-based enum in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, enums

I am looking for an enum-based approach to return an array behind each enum item. For example, suppose that I need to specify a range for each type of target such as the following:

```py
from enum import Enum 

class TargetRange(Enum):
    T1 = [0, 100]
    T2 = [30, 60]
    T3 = [50, 150]
```

Now, I am using the enum like the following:

```py
target_range = TargetRange.T1
value = 140

# ...
# adjust the value

if(value > target_range[1]):
    value = target_range[1]
elif(value < target_range[0]):
    value = target_range[0]
# ...
```

But, I get the following error:

> TypeError: 'TargetRange' object is not subscriptable

How can I resolve it? What is the correct usage of this kind of enum?

I should note that I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58608361/string-based-enum-in-python) to return a string (instead of an array). Hence, I am looking for the same idea for returning array instead of a string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are three ways to get support for indexing:

- use the `.value` attribute

  ```
  TargetRange.T1.value
  ```
- inherit from `list` as well as `Enum`:

  ```
  class TargetRange(list, Enum):
  ```
- add the `__getitem__` method:

  ```
  class TargetRange(Enum):
      def __getitem__(self, index):
          return self._value_[index]
      T1 = [0, 100]
      T2 = [30, 60]
      T3 = [50, 150]
  ```

It is also possible to add behavior to Python enums, which can simplify code elsewhere.  For example:

```
class TargetRange(Enum):
    T1 = [0, 100]
    T2 = [30, 60]
    T3 = [50, 150]
    #
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self._value_[index]
    #
    def limit(self, value):
        # adjust the value
        if(value > self[1]):
            value = self[1]
        elif(value < self[0]):
            value = self[0]
        return value
```

then in the main code:

```
>>> TargetRange.T1.limit(140)
100
```

---

Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between `Enum` and `StrEnum` is exactly at this point. If you print `TargetRange.T1`, you will find that the value of the enum item is not returned. Hence, a simple solution to resolve this issue is rewriting your first line of the code as follow:

```py
target_range = TargtetRange.T1.value
#...
```

It means using `.value` property of the enum item instead of directly using the enum item.