# Is there a way to use StrEnum in earlier python versions?

Tags: python, enums

The enum package in python 3.11 has the StrEnum class. I consider it very convenient but cannot use it in python 3.10.  What would be the easiest method to use this class anyway?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58608361/string-based-enum-in-python

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On Python 3.10, you can inherit from `str` and `Enum` to have a `StrEnum`:

```py
from enum import Enum


class MyEnum(str, Enum):
    choice1 = "choice1"
    choice2 = "choice2"
```

With this approach, you have string comparison:

```py
"choice1" == MyEnum.choice1
>> True
```

Be aware, however, that Python 3.11 makes a breaking change to classes which inherit from (str, Enum): https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/100458. You will have to change all instances of (str, Enum) to StrEnum when upgrading to maintain the same behavior.

**Or**:

you can execute `pip install StrEnum` and have this:

```py
from strenum import StrEnum


class MyEnum(StrEnum):
    choice1 = "choice1"
    choice2 = "choice2"
```

Comment: note that the first option still has limitations. for example, you can't do `"choice1" in iter(MyEnum)`. i don't know how the second option works.

Answer (score 1):

[irgeek](https://github.com/irgeek) on GitHub has a well-rounded StrEnum package that is installable through pip.

https://github.com/irgeek/StrEnum

```
python3 -m pip install StrEnum
```

Their documentation says it's compatible with Python 3.7+.  However, I'm using it with Python 3.6.8 without any issues.