# Python Enum with auto generated string names for typer

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, enums

I'm using `python 3.8.10` with `typer 0.7.0` and wanting to use an enum I have defined in my project as an input argument.

I've previously used something like the following with argparse and, alongside setting `choices=list(ModelTypeEnum)`, it's worked fine - note that this is a short example, I have many more values that in some places require the numerical values assigned.

```py
class ModelTypeEnum(Enum):
    ALEXNET = 0
    RESNET50 = 1
    VGG19 = 2

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

However using something like this with typer expects the argument to be an integer

```py
app = typer.Typer()

@app.command()
def main(model_type: ModelTypeEnum = typer.Argument(..., help="Model to choose")):
    ...
    return 0
```

```
click.exceptions.BadParameter: 'RESNET50' is not one of 0, 1, 2.
```

While this example is short and could be converted to an `(str, Enum)` I would like a solution where I don't need to specify the string names manually and still have integers associated with each item - is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Why won't you use an approach similar to the one in this question: [String-based enum in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58608361/string-based-enum-in-python)?

```
class ModelTypeEnum(str, Enum):
    ALEXNET = 'ALEXNET'
    RESNET50 = 'RESNET50'
    VGG19 = 'VGG19'
```

You do not need to implement `__str__` method because objects of `ModelTypeEnum` are of both classes: `str` and `Enum`. So there is no need to introduce integer-based Enum class. It can be string from the start.