# iterating list with enum of string

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, enums

I have a

```
myenum(str, Enum):
   COLORRED = 'colorred'
   COLORBLUE = 'colorblue'

itemList = [<myenum.COLORRED,'colorred'>]
```

I am trying to get value from itemList 'coloured' but `itemList.value` gives a type check error in Python with the error message "str has no attribute value".

list(map(str,myenum)) gives key COLORRED but I need the value 'coloured'. I tried [String-based enum in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58608361/string-based-enum-in-python) but none of them are working for me.

My enum is auto generated by openapi. below is yaml for it.
I receive array of myElements and need one value in myEnum.

```
myElements:
  type: array
  items:
  allOf:
     - $ref: 'myEnum'

myEnum:
  type: String
  enum:
    - 'state1'
    - 'state2'
```

Note: Issue is with typecheck in python not iterating the values. I need enum values without using .values or .name

Comment: Please update your question with a complete snippet of code that we can run to see the problem ourselves.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're trying to use the list's `.value` property, not its elements.

```py
from enum import Enum

class Color(Enum):
    RED = "color red"
    BLUE = "color blue"

lst = [Color.RED, Color.BLUE]
expected = ['color red', 'color blue']

# This is equivalent to `list(map(lambda v: v.value, lst))`
values = [item.value for item in lst]
assert values == expected
```

Comment: I tried this way but still get type check error "str has no attribute value". can we iterate without .value and get the value instead of key?

Comment: @shekharpandey I cannot reproduce that. From the error message, it sounds like the elements of your list are strings, not your enum members. Make sure your data is what you expect it to be.

Comment: You are correct, but my list is like this itemList = [<myenum.COLORRED, 'colorred'>] and I just want 'coloured'.  Also its work fine but typecheck is giving error.

Comment: @shekharpandey yeah sorry, I can't reproduce your behavior on Python3 or Python2. You should try to figure out what your object is, because based on the error message you're incorrect about that :)

Answer (score 0):

Your point is not exactly clear to me, but...

If you are using [Python 3.11](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.11.html) you can use [StrEnum](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/enum.html#enum.StrEnum), so you can get the value without calling `.value`.

```
class Color(StrEnum):
    RED = 'red'
    GREEN = 'green'
    BLUE = 'blue'

print(Color.RED) #=> red
```

There is also [IntEnum](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/enum.html#enum.IntEnum).

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are after is the values of the enum in a list. If so, this may be something you can work with.

```
from enum import Enum

class myenum(str, Enum):
    COLORRED = 'colorred'
    COLORBLUE = 'colorblue'

mylist = [x.value for x in myenum]
# where mylist will be ['colorred', 'colorblue']
```

However, if you explain how you generate your list and how you would like to use the data (perhaps with a simple example), that might help the people to understand your objectives better.

Comment: @ dakdad Sorry for clarity, I have updated post. mylist = [x.value for x in myenum] is working but type check tool give error "str has no attribute value"